# CSS, p tag, fill as much space as possible when shrink browser after certain point

Tags: html, css, tags, resize

First of all, want to say, that I'm not a front-end engineer and my skills of UI and UX are very low.

So my question is:
I have a div with `p` tags inside. I want to have it `width: 700px` when the browser window is maximized. But if I put this property in CSS of my div. The text will not shrink if I resize the window. So I want to have it up to a certain point while window is maximized and shrink it if you resize the window, without affecting side-bar div.

To be more clear I will give you an example:

## Maximazed Browser window:

[image]

## Minimized Browser window:

[image]

## HTML

```
 <!-- HOME -->
  <div id="home" class="content">
   <h2>Home</h2>
   <p>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</p>
   <p>BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB</p>
  </div>
```

## CSS

```
.content {
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 280px;
    right: 40px;
    top: 0px;
}
.content h2 {
    font-size: 110px;
    color: #fff;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
    padding: 10px 0 20px 0;
    margin-top: 50px; 
}
.content p {
    color: black;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 24px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: take a look at css media queries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use Media Queries in your case, but that would be the case in more complicated cases (different breakpoints for example).

Just use `max-width: 700px` and you're done.

Normal behavior: your paragraph is never wider than 700px.
With very small widths, paragraph occupies the whole width as would any block element and it's still smaller than 700px so no need for MQ!

See this fiddle to see it into effect: http://jsfiddle.net/LQbgJ/ (I used 200px instead of 700)
Compatibility should be IE7+

Comment: Yep, I agree. Un context to the actual questions problem, this should be marked as the correct answer. Media queries are great but a bit over the top for this one purpose. Plus, max-width would be better supported at this stage.

Comment: You are right, `max-width` will do the trick, in a very simple way.

Answer (score 2):

What you want are [Media Queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/). Take a look at the W3C recommendations for them.

Basically, the syntax is as follows:

```
@media screen and (min/max-width: ){ 
  //do something

}
```

These are called 'break points'. Which means, at the point where the browser reaches the min/max width you provide, you can over-rule other css. So you can make your `p` and `div` sizes different.

```
    @media screen and (min/max-width: ){ 

      div {
          width: 200px;
       }

       p {
          font-size: 20px;
       }
    }
```

Also take a look at [Smashing Magazine](http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/)'s tutorial on how to use them.

Comment: WOW, thanks a lot for your answer, didn't know that CSS has such a cool thing. That's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I chose to go the MQ route because they're great, and as far as I can tell the `p` font-size gets bigger, no? Sure it's good practice for the future if not, anyway. :)